# VBA going from rows to columns

Tags: excel, vba

My code currently pastes to one singular column all the files I copy.

I need it to go to a different column for each new file instead of one row.

I.e. file1 to col1 file2 to col 2 etc

Would it involve changing the .row to columns or a new command in general?

Here's the code

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub CopyDataFromDump()
    Dim SourceFolder As String
    Dim nSourceFolder As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim Wb As Workbook
    Dim CopyFromSheet As Worksheet
    Dim PasteToSheet As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long

    SourceFolder = "" ' folder path where your workbooks are located

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim oFSO As Variant
    Dim oFolder As Variant
    Dim oFile As File
    Dim MyFSO As FileSystemObject

    Set MyFSO = New FileSystemObject

    Set oFolder = MyFSO.GetFolder(SourceFolder)

    For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
      Set Wb = Workbooks.Open(oFile, , Format:=5) 'open each workbook in the folder
      Set CopyFromSheet = Wb.Sheets(1) ' sheet from where you want to copy data
      Set PasteToSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) ' sheet from where you want to paste data

      CopyFromSheet.UsedRange.Copy   ' Copy data from the specified sheet in the opened workbook

      LastRow = PasteToSheet.Cells(PasteToSheet.Row.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1     ' Find the last row in the paste sheet

      PasteToSheet.Cells(LastRow, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues  ' Paste data into the destination sheet in the active workbook

      Wb.Close False  ' Close the opened workbook
    Next oFile
End Sub
```

I tried Active.sheets.cell.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `UsedRange` doesn't have empty cells in Row 1:

```
Dim NextCol As Long
'...
'...
'Find the paste column in the destination sheet
NextCol = PasteToSheet.Cells(1,PasteToSheet.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 1     

PasteToSheet.Cells(1, NextCol).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```